# python : Remote host is closing connection while downloading files from http server

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, python-requests

I am using below function to download files form http Server. 
Code is working, however need to optimize in term of chunk it's downloading.

```
def download_bits(bits):
    for link in bits:
        filename = link.split('/')[-1]
        print filename
        print "Downloading File : {0}".format(filename)

        resp = requests.get(link, stream=True)

        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)

        print "File {0} Downloaded.! ".format(filename)
    print "All Downloads are Completed.!"
```

I have executed this code to validate the functionality, and remote connection closed the connection. How can i avoid this ?

```
Downloading file:CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1708.iso
CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1708.iso downloaded!

Downloading file:CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1708.iso
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ChunkedEncodingError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-381f54eff57b> in <module>()
     15     # download started
     16     with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
---> 17         for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
     18             if chunk:
     19                 f.write(chunk)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\requests\models.pyc in generate()
    739                         yield chunk
    740                 except ProtocolError as e:
--> 741                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    742                 except DecodeError as e:
    743                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)

ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')", error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `stream=True`, `requests`  will not download the response body by itself, so it will keep the connection opened until you use `.iter_content()` or `.iter_lines()` to read the entire response.

If it is opened for too long without activity, the server may choose to close the connection.

Hard to tell why this happens, but I'd say your chunk size is too large for the underlying network.

Try [`chunk_size=None`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) to have `requests` giving you the chunks as they are received by the network interface:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as foutput:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
        if chunk:
            foutput.write(chunk)
```

Don't worry about optimizing the chunk size, since the OS I/O layer has its own buffer for disk writing.

Comment: I tried `chunk_size=None` but didn't help.
it's throwing below exception.
`  for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 619, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: IncompleteRead(1235756 bytes read, 4520223956 more expected. `

Comment: @tgcloud: What kind of network connection are you plugged to ? And what kind of disk are you writing to ? What about chunk_size=1 ?

Comment: I have writing on SSD, and network is behind the firewall. 
I tried with `chunk_size=1024*1024` and `chunk_size=None` on my internal http server both are working for me. I am able to download `> 5GB` of Qcow2 files.  Where on CentOS repo I am permitted to download only file with few MB only (May be because i am behind firewall. (another possibility CentOS http server might be restricting this not sure though) i will continue investigation on this from my home network and update.